# Is it ever known which peoples of the Hainish universe were results of genetic experimentation or manipulation?

Tags: ursula-k-le-guin, the-left-hand-of-darkness, hainish-cycle

In *The Left Hand of Darkness* a theory is mentioned that the Gethenians may have been the result of some type of genetic manipulation or experimentation in their distant past. This speculation was cited as one explanation for their apparently uncommon and astounding hermaphroditic physiology.

I think in the same book it was mentioned that certain other peoples of the known universe might also have similar origins.

Is this ever explored further? Does the possibly Hainish history of genetic manipulation ever become known?

Comment: Thing is all these different human races are supposed to stem from Hains and hermaphroditism is hardly something that could evolve during a few million years. It's more tricky in case of other races and we know little about Hains' past doings.